# Load a html file

Tags: php

Probably i didnt explain very well, i updated the code to turn more easy to see what i want.

I need to load a external html file in that "div external_page....", i thing that the best way is to load a file in the php file(External PHP content), tell me if im wrong :)

This is the demo: http://vasplus.info/demos/load_and_refresh_div_every_10_seconds/index.php

**(UPDATE)**

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.js"></script>

<div id="external_page_content_displayer">External page contents will be here</div>


<!-- EXTERNAL PHP CONTENTS-->
  <?php
srand((float) microtime() * 10005224);

$lines = file('ajax/rssatom/rss-atom.html');

$This_Page_Content = array($lines, 
    "teste","teste","teste");

$This_Page_Content_Rand_Keys = array_rand($This_Page_Content, 2);
$This_Page_Content_Displayer = $This_Page_Content[$This_Page_Content_Rand_Keys[0]] . "\n";
echo strip_tags($This_Page_Content_Displayer);
?>



 <!-- LOAD FUNCTION-->

<script>

    function Load_external_content()
    {
        $('#external_page_content_displayer').load('external_content.php').hide().fadeIn(3000);
    }
    setInterval('Load_external_content()', 10000);

    </script>
```

Regards

Comment: `echo $rs;` is incorrect. You can just do `$rs`

Comment: have you tried `array($rs.....` ?

Comment: Sorry, dont work, not loading the page :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
$lines = file('ajax/rssatom/rss-atom.html');
```